# Kendo Chart - displaying the last X records in a pannable/zoomable chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, zooming

Kendo team released their pannable/zoomable chart recently.

I would like to use it but I have the following problem: I need to display only the last X records of the available ones, and display the rest on zoom/ mouse move.
The example they presented on their site: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom displays the data starting from c0 to c10.

I would like to see the last 10 records from c89 to c99 instead of the first 10.

How to achieve that - can you please advice.

Answer (score 1):

In their example, set the min and max of the category axis:

```
           categoryAxis: {
                min: 90,
                max: 99,
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
```

Updated **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/Asoqa)**